# Password verify option to check for false in php

Tags: php

We are using password_verify in php to check if password is correct or not... and commonly used as follows....

```
$hash = '$2y$10$SwSqhfgfghdhooyut54quJQ28fQbNY1Q3JdTFnoe.2VxD/D2RXBS';
$password = 'Rf@1P9812JG';

if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
  echo 'Password is valid!';
 } else {
   echo 'Invalid password.';
 }
```

**My question is, can we use it as follows ?**

```
$hash = '$2y$10$SwSqhfgfghdhooyut54quJQ28fQbNY1Q3JdTFnoe.2VxD/D2RXBS';
$password = 'Rf@1P9812JG';

if (!password_verify($password, $hash)) {
  echo 'Invalid password!';
}
```

I just want to check if password is wrong... and if it is wrong, show error...

Comment: Sure, why not? It returns `true` or `false`. You decide what to do from there.

Answer (score 2):

**Sure you can**

If you check PHP's documentation for the [`password_verify`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) function, you can see it says:

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns TRUE if the password and hash match, or FALSE otherwise.

So `(!password_verify($password, $hash))` will indicate that the function returned false, so the verification failed. It is valid to output an error at this point.